# .htaccess RewriteRule not working for two values with same code

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Doctors Code (Working)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^doctors/([0-9]+)\/([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/?$ doc.php?doc_code=$1&firstname=$2&lastname=$3 [L,NC,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^doctors/([0-9]+)\/([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/?$ doc.php?doc_code=$1&firstname=$2&lastname=$3&action=$4 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Pharmacy Code (Not Working)

```
RewriteRule ^/pharmacy/([0-9]+)\/([a-z]+)\/?$ pharmacy.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,NC,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^/pharmacy/([0-9]+)\/([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/?$ pharmacy.php?id=$1&name=$2&action=$3 [L,NC,R=301]
```

When I Am Using The Code Below, It Works Fine For Pharmacy But Purpose Is Not Solved Because I Want The Link To Look As '/Pharmacy' & not '/Doctors':

```
 RewriteRule ^/doctors/([0-9]+)\/([a-z]+)\/?$ pharmacy.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,NC,R=301] 
    RewriteRule ^/doctors/([0-9]+)\/([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/?$ pharmacy.php?id=$1&name=$2&action=$3 [L,NC,R=301]
```

The full .htacess code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Header unset ETag
FileETag None


RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^doctors/([0-9]+)\/([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/?$ doc.php?doc_code=$1&firstname=$2&lastname=$3 [L,NC,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^doctors/([0-9]+)\/([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/?$ doc.php?doc_code=$1&firstname=$2&lastname=$3&action=$4 [L,NC,QSA] 

RewriteRule ^pharmacy/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ pharmacy.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,NC,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^pharmacy/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ pharmacy.php?id=$1&name=$2&action=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out leading slash and turn off `MultiViews` option:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^pharmacy/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ pharmacy.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,NC,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^pharmacy/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ pharmacy.php?id=$1&name=$2&action=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Also you don't need `R=301` as you don't want to show your internal URL in browsers.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have updated my question with the full .htaccess code. Please check.

Comment: What is the full URL you used and what error you got?

Comment: Full Link: http://bermuda.aoctor.com/pharmacy/154/geetamedicalhall
Error: Not fetching data using id number from link.

Comment: Did you use `Option -MultiViews` as I suggested in answer?

Comment: Ah it should be `Options -MultiViews` (see updated answer)